# Customer Error: Record could not be parsed to valid data point

Tags: python, prediction, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I've been trying to run ensemble prediction from multiple models based on [this example](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction_to_applying_machine_learning/ensemble_modeling/EnsembleLearnerCensusIncome.html) and I managed to add KNN to the other two algorithms. However, I'm facing this error during the prediction step (copied from CloudWatch):

> Customer Error: Record could not be parsed to valid data point. Please make sure the data is valid and try again. (caused by KeyError)

Here is how I built the ensemble model and the endpoint:

```
# build a model

sm_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

model_name = "MODEL-for-ensemble-modelling-" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
xgboost_hosting_container = {
    "Image": xgb_container,
    "ContainerHostname": "xgboost",
    "ModelDataUrl": sm.describe_training_job(TrainingJobName=xgboost_job_name)
    ["ModelArtifacts"]["S3ModelArtifacts"],
}



linear_hosting_container = {
    "Image": container,
    "ContainerHostname": "linear",
    "ModelDataUrl": sm.describe_training_job(TrainingJobName=linear_job_name)["ModelArtifacts"][
        "S3ModelArtifacts"
    ],
}



knn_hosting_container = {
    "Image": knn_container,
    "ContainerHostname": "knn",
    "ModelDataUrl": sm.describe_training_job(TrainingJobName=knn_job_name)["ModelArtifacts"][
        "S3ModelArtifacts"
    ],
}

#inferenceExecutionConfig = {"Mode": "Direct"}




model = sm_client.create_model( ModelName=model_name,
                                  #InferenceExecutionConfig=inferenceExecutionConfig,
                                  ExecutionRoleArn=role,
                                  Containers=[xgboost_hosting_container, linear_hosting_container, knn_hosting_container],)
    



print('Model created: '+ model['ModelArn'])


#Specify data configuration setting

s3_capture_upload_path = 's3://{}/{}/monitoring/datacapture'.format(rawbucket, prefix)

data_capture_configuration = {
    "EnableCapture": True,
    "InitialSamplingPercentage": 100,
    "DestinationS3Uri": s3_capture_upload_path,
    "CaptureOptions": [
        { "CaptureMode": "Output" },
        { "CaptureMode": "Input" }
    ],
    "CaptureContentTypeHeader": {
       "CsvContentTypes": ["text/csv"],
       "JsonContentTypes": ["application/json"]}}



#Create endpoint configuration

def create_endpoint_config(model_config, data_capture_config): 
    return sm_client.create_endpoint_config(
                                                EndpointConfigName=model_config,
                                                ProductionVariants=[
                                                        {
                                                            'VariantName': 'AllTraffic',
                                                            'ModelName': model_name,
                                                            'InitialInstanceCount': 1,
                                                            'InstanceType': 'ml.m4.xlarge',
                                                            'InitialVariantWeight': 1.0,
                                                },
                                                    
                                                    ],
                                                DataCaptureConfig=data_capture_config
                                                )

endpoint_config = create_endpoint_config(model_name, data_capture_configuration)

print('Endpoint configuration created: '+ endpoint_config['EndpointConfigArn'])


#Create endpoint

def create_endpoint(endpoint_name, config_name):
    return sm_client.create_endpoint(
                                    EndpointName=model_name,
                                    EndpointConfigName=model_name
                                )
endpoint = create_endpoint(model_name, endpoint_config)

    
print('Endpoint created: '+ endpoint['EndpointArn'])
```

And here is the prediction step:

```
datas = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv',header = None)

datas = datas.drop(columns = 0)

datas = datas.sample(n=87)


#Sending inference requests to the multimodel endpoint

from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer
from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer

predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name=model_name,
                      serializer=CSVSerializer(),
                      deserializer=JSONDeserializer())
response = predictor.predict(datas.values)

print('done!')
```

The traceback is:

```
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-f8fe7afa50b9> in <module>
      8                       serializer=CSVSerializer(),
      9                       deserializer=JSONDeserializer())
---> 10 response = predictor.predict(datas.values)
     11 
     12 print('done!')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id)
    159             data, initial_args, target_model, target_variant, inference_id
    160         )
--> 161         response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    162         return self._handle_response(response)
    163 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528                 )
    529             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 530             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    531 
    532         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    958             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    959             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 960             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    961         else:
    962             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from knn with message "unable to evaluate payload provided".
```

And here is what CloudWatch logs show:

```
Customer Error: Record could not be parsed to valid data point. Please make sure the data is valid and try again. (caused by KeyError)
Caused by: 'instances'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ai_algorithms_sdk/io/serve_helpers.py", line 78, in _iterator_points_dense_rank_2
    points = get_points(payload)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ai_algorithms_sdk/io/serve_helpers.py", line 93, in _get_points
    return [_load_json_instance(instance) for instance in raw_data["instances"]]

KeyError: 'instances'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ai_algorithms_sdk/serve.py", line 722, in get_invocation_response
    data_iter = get_data_iterator(payload, **content_parameters)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ai_algorithms_sdk/io/serve_helpers.py", line 94, in iterator_json_dense_rank_2
    return _iterator_points_dense_rank_2(payload, _get_points)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ai_algorithms_sdk/io/serve_helpers.py", line 80, in _iterator_points_dense_rank_2
    raise NonParsableRecordCustomerError(caused_by=e)


ai_algorithms_sdk.io.serve_helpers.NonParsableRecordCustomerError: Record could not be parsed to valid data point. Please make sure the data is valid and try again. (caused by KeyError)
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: CHECK IN the code if you have used "instances" anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try DataFrame.to_numpy() instead.  There is a problem with the CSV Serializer not being able to serialize your data correctly.  https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/serializers.py
Read on for some other alternatives.

The error message is looking for "instances" in the request, which is the root of the JSON inference format.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-inference.html#ir-serialization
So the issue would likely be that there is a problem with the csv serialization for the request via the predictor.
There is a lot going on with your endpoint (data capture configs, etc). You could consider narrowing it down a bit by commenting those out and seeing if the code now works.  You could also create a fake inference string both in CSV and JSON and see if the endpoint takes it.  Once the model is deployed you can also make a [call via boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime/client/invoke_endpoint.html) At least this will give you an idea whether your issue is with the endpoint or the input.  Getting the right input to the endpoint can be difficult to troubleshoot with all the convenience functions (Sagemaker predictor w/ serializers).  I suggest trying to troubleshoot around that.